# Linear dependence of a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is the following a correct description of a linearly dependent set of vectors:

A set of vectors $S$ (in a vector space $V$) is said to be $\textbf {linearly dependent}$  if there exists $\textbf {distinct}$ vectors $ \mathbf{v}_{1}, \ldots , \mathbf{v}_{m} \in S$ and scalars $c^{1}, \ldots, c^{m} \in \mathbb{F}$ (where $\mathbb{F}$ is the underlying scalar field of the vector space $V$), not all of which are zero, such that $$c^{1}\mathbf{v}_{1}+\cdots +c^{m}\mathbf{v}_{m}= \sum_{i=1}^{m}c^{i}\mathbf{v}_{i} = \mathbf{0}$$

What this means is that $\textbf {at least one}$ vector in $S$ can be completely specified in terms of the other vectors in the set and hence is dependent on the remaining vectors in the set $S$. In this sense, if one vector can be 'constructed' from a linear combination of the remaining vectors in $S$, then there is a relationship between these vectors; the existence of this vector in $S$ is dependent on the other (remaining) vectors in the set (i.e. it does not exist independently relative to the set $S$ as it is a combination of the other vectors in the set).

Importantly, however, the property of linear dependence pertains to a set of vectors and $\textbf{not}$ to any particular vector. As such, although relative to a particular set of vectors a given vector may not have an independent existence (as it is formed from a linear combination of the other vectors in that set), when considered individually (outside of any given set of vectors) it does exist as an independent mathematical object.

Comment: Everything you said up until the last paragraph is exactly correct. In the last paragraph, you seem to be conflating linear independence with "independent existence." I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that. All of the vectors in $V$ exist, regardless of which ones can be written as linear combinations of others.

Comment: @Bungo Ah, ok. Yes, I wasn't sure about the last paragraph when I wrote it. I guess I was trying to reiterate that relative to a given set, if a vector is linear combination of the remaining vectors in that set then in a sense it does not have an independent existence in that set, as it resides within the span of the remaining subset of vectors, such that its 'removal' would not affect the number of vectors we could describe with the remaining vectors?!

Comment: P.S. You are correct that linear dependence is a property of *sets* of vectors. For example, think about what it means goemetrically for, say, three vectors to be linearly dependent in $\mathbb{R}^3$. It simply means that all three vectors lie in the same plane. If none of them is the zero vector, and none lie in the same line, then if you remove any of the three vectors (it doesn't matter which one), then the remaining two will be linearly independent.

Comment: What you said in your last comment is mostly correct. However, linear dependence of a set of vectors doesn't necessarily mean that there is a specific vector which is to blame for linear dependence. This *can* be true, for example, if one of them is the zero vector. But it can also mean that you just have too many vectors.

Comment: Yes, I see. I was trying really to give a meaning to the notion of $dependence$ between a set of vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a correct description.